# HTML 5 offline applicatin failed to load cached resource

Tags: html, manifest, cache-manifest

I have cache static resources of my website using [manifest file](http://wmp5.persiabme.com/manifest.aspx) 
But when I run website when internet is not connected images not shown.
Images also should cache because I putted them in manifest file.
For example I have cached [this file](http://wmp5.persiabme.com/styles/Image/bg.png) but this file is not loaded when the Internet is disconnected.

Here is [google chrome console snapshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54490657/Stackoverflow/Snapshot_2012-03-28_113806.png) :

[image: Google chrome console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its strange .. 
The problem resolved just when I changed images folder name !

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem. I included below in the cache.manifest file & it fixed for me.

```
NETWORK:
*
```